# When SaveAS through macro, file saves as xlsx with 6mb

Tags: vba, excel, save, range

I have an Excel Workbook where I have a bunch of macros. One of them is to save that file in .xlsx, deleting other sheets, leaving just one and cleaning out the macros and VBA code.

The problem is, when i "export" it, the file saves as 6mb, even when I save it with no values in columns and rows. I tried to copy the used ranged and to paste it as values but it's not working.

I think my workbook is assuming it as thousands of cells, when I have only one when I use ctrl + shift + right/down.

Can you help me? Even copy and pasting all as values isn't working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code. We can only help on what we can see.

Comment: Large excel file sizes sometimes result from formmating left in the document. Try to clear all formats before saving and recheck file size (https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/07/14/clear-formatting-excel/)